# Linq select from two tables order by list

Tags: c#, sql, linq, select, sql-order-by

I have two tables in DB from which I want to select. In one of them 'Events' I have events (Id, start, end, type) and in the other I have 'Events_before_after' where I collect events that are linked with some of the events from 'Events' - (Id, EventId, start, end, type).
I have also a list of ids of Events by which I need to order the events in select query.

This is what I have:

```
List<int> orderIds = ...

from order in orderIds
join event in events order on order equals event.id
select new DataEvent ()
{
    eventId = event.Id,
    start = event.start,
    end = event.end,
    type = event.type
}).Concat
from eventOther in Events_before_after
select new DataEvent ()
{
    eventId = eventOther.Id,
    start = eventOther.start,
    end = eventOther.end,
    type = eventOther.type
}
```

Is it possible to order also the second select? I mean - is there way to order it by `eventId` which links to 'Events'?

What I need is:

```
event1
event2
eventBefore3
event3
eventAfter3
```

what I have is:

```
event1
event2
event3
eventBefore3
eventAfter3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 //your query
 ...
from eventOther in Events_before_after
select new DataEvent ()
{
    eventId = eventOther.Id,
    start = eventOther.start,
    end = eventOther.end,
    type = eventOther.type
}
into NewEvent
order by NewEvent.eventId
select NewEvent;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I get your gist you want to group together related events on a given key, order them, then project and flatten them along a given ordering of keys.... If you want to do that try the following:

```
var orderedEvents = orderIds.Join(
                     //Construct Groups 
                     events.GroupBy( e => e.Id)
                           .GroupJoin( Events_before_after,
                                       g => g.Key,
                                       e => e.EventId,
                                       (gEvent, gEventBA) => new { Key = gEvent.Key,
                                       EventGroup = 
                                       gEvent.Select( e => new DataEvent ()
                                                     {
                                                      eventId = e.Id,
                                                      start = e.start,
                                                      end = e.end,
                                                      type = e.type
                                                     })
                                              .Concat( gEventBA.Select( e => new DataEvent ()
                                                                {
                                                                 eventId = e.Id,
                                                                 start = e.start,
                                                                 end = e.end,
                                                                 type = e.type
                                                                }))
                                              .OrderBy(e => e.eventId)),
                      //Project along keys
                      o => o,
                      anon => anon.Key,
                      (o,anon) => anon.EventGroup)
                      //Flatten groups
                           .SelectMany( g => g);
```